# How do I call the credentials, a user entered in a login dialog prompt, to my main and print in in Java?

Tags: java, actionlistener, jdialog, actionevent

How do I call `user` and `pw` in the method `actionPerformed()`, which equal to the credentials the user entered in the login dialog prompt to my main so I can reference it, or print it out there?

I tried setting up some getters and setters but I kept getting a `NullPointerException`.

LoginDialog class:

```
public class LoginDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

public String user;
public char [] pw;

private String OK = "ok";
private String HELP = "help";

private JFrame controllingFrame; // needed for dialogs
private JTextField userField;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
private TransferService transferService;
BaselineTransferFrame btf;

public LoginDialog(JDialog loginDialog, BaselineTransferFrame bltFrame) {
    // Use the default FlowLayout.
    controllingFrame = (JFrame) loginDialog.getParent();
    transferService = bltFrame.getTransferService();
    btf = bltFrame;

    // Create everything.
    userField = new JTextField(12);
    passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
    passwordField.setActionCommand(OK);
    passwordField.addActionListener(this);

    JLabel uLabel = new JLabel("Enter your Dimensions User ID: ");
    JLabel pLabel = new JLabel("Enter password: ");
    uLabel.setLabelFor(userField);
    pLabel.setLabelFor(passwordField);



    // Lay out everything.
    JPanel textPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    textPane.add(uLabel);
    textPane.add(userField);
    textPane.add(pLabel);
    textPane.add(passwordField);
    textPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10), new EtchedBorder()));

    JComponent buttonPane = createButtonPanel(textPane);

    add(textPane);
    add(buttonPane);

}

protected JComponent createButtonPanel(JPanel p) {
    float BTN_SIZE = 16f;
    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    okButton.setActionCommand(OK);
    helpButton.setActionCommand(HELP);
    okButton.addActionListener(this);
    helpButton.addActionListener(this);
    okButton.setFont(okButton.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, BTN_SIZE));
    helpButton.setFont(helpButton.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, BTN_SIZE));       

    Boolean enabled = true;
    if (enabled) {
        okButton.setBackground(new Color(59, 89, 182));
        okButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        okButton.setBackground(new Color(128, 128, 128));
        okButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
    okButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    okButton.setFocusPainted(false);

    if (enabled) {
        helpButton.setBackground(new Color(59, 89, 182));
        helpButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        helpButton.setBackground(new Color(128, 128, 128));
        helpButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
    helpButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    helpButton.setFocusPainted(false);

    p.add(okButton);
    p.add(helpButton);

    return p;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

    if (OK.equals(cmd)) { // Process the password.
        user = userField.getText();
        pw = passwordField.getPassword();
        HashMap<String, String> connectParms = transferService.getConnectionParms("a");
        DimensionsSession dmSession = null;
        try {
            dmSession = transferService.connectToDimensions(connectParms.get("server"), connectParms.get("connection"), connectParms.get("database"), user, String.valueOf(pw));
            System.out.println("Here");
        } catch (BaselineTransferException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (dmSession != null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controllingFrame, "Success! You typed the right password.");
            dmSession.close();
            controllingFrame.dispose();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controllingFrame, "Invalid password. Try again.", "Error Message",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        // Zero out the possible password, for security.
        Arrays.fill(pw, '0');

        passwordField.selectAll();
        resetFocus();
    } else { // The user has asked for help.
        System.exit(0);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controllingFrame,
                "You can get the password by searching this example's\n"
                        + "source code for the string \"correctPassword\".\n"
                        + "Or look at the section How to Use Password Fields in\n"
                        + "the components section of The Java Tutorial.");
    }
}
```

Comment: strange code `System.exit(0);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controllingFrame,....`  - you are calling code after exit.

Comment: Anyway please show your stacktrace

Comment: It just gives me null

Comment: Ok, so you don't want me to help you - got it.

Comment: I no longer get a nullpointerexception, when I set up a simple getter that returns user and call it in the main and try to print user it just gives me "null"